# Are there free maps available that can show me land planted with oil palm?

Tags: imagery, landsat, land-survey

Currently I am taking gps coordinates of oil palm plantations in Africa. I'm putting the waypoints in a GIS program but the free basemap provided isn't always giving high resolution images, making it difficult to adjust the waypoints to the real boundaries of a plantation. On Google Earth you can detect plantations easily. So I was wondering which free imagery is available to detect plantation boundaries/palm trees. Or is there a way to detect oil palm plantations from low resolution imagery (landsat).

Comment: what is the neighbor crop of the plantation?

Comment: Landsat imagery is very well suited for use in detecting oil palm plantations.  This is typically done in an automated fashion using image classification techniques (e.g. supervised maximum liklihood, random forests, SVM, etc).

Answer (score 2):

http://commodities.globalforestwatch.org/ has a Palm Oil concessions layer under the contextual maps, land use category. Coverage seems limited to Indonesia, Brazil, and Western Africa.